# How to show and hide DIV in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two div(s)

```
<div id = 'a'>
</div>
<div id = 'b'>
</div>
```

click on "add" button i want to hide div a and show div b

Comment: The dude didn't even get a warning???   Baptism by fire  - doubt he wants to ever ask another question at the church of stackoverflow.   I didn't bother looking up his profile, but what if he can  a. code circle around you in some other language  AND/OR  b. he was running to a meeting and just started his question and journey into angular.   Instead I see -8 on his question and no comments about how he can be pro-active in researching a bit first.   Zero point in telling someone to hire a programmer.

Comment: well said Tom. Sometimes I wonder if the some of the SO community are machines that haven't been taught to be human.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would adapt your html markup like this:

```
<div ng-controller="controller">     
    <div id = 'a' ng-show="showA">
    </div>
    <div id = 'b' ng-show="showB">
    </div>
    <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
</div>
```

And then, in your controller, have something like this:

```
function controller($scope) {
    $scope.showA = true;
    $scope.showB = false;

    $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.showA = false;
        $scope.showB = true;
    };
}
```

Comment: you're welcome - please consider accepting my answer if it helped you, or feel free to ask for more details, if anything is unclear.